# What are the TV/movie Discworld adaptations?

Tags: movie, tv, discworld, adaptations

So... I've seen the *Hogfather* and *Colour of Magic*/*Light Fantastic* via YouTube... think they were pretty good, but the video/audio quality was poor.  And I understand *Going Postal* is out there as well (gonna hunt it down shortly... I hope).  I've also seen some cartoon versions of *Wyrd Sisters*, etc.

So... how many adaptations are there, both live action and animated? Where were they released?

Comment: Leave out the parts where you ask about how to obtain these, as "[shopping](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/499/21267)" or recommendation questions are [off-topic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, however the rest is fine. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

According to the Discworld wiki, there are a few more titles than offered in the search proposed by DJClayworth's post.

The link here [Discworld Adaptations](https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/TV_and_film_adaptations) gives all titles, including those, but not limited to the titles you have already seen.

Should anyone not be able to access the link, the adaptations are

- Truckers, 1992, an animated series by Cosgrove Hall.
- Johnny and the Dead, a TV serial by ITV, 1995.
- Soul Music, 1997, an animated series by Cosgrove Hall.
- Wyrd Sisters, 1997, an animated series by Cosgrove Hall.
- Johnny and the Bomb, 2006, a three-part TV series on the BBC.
- Hogfather, aired by Sky One, Christmas 2006 as TV film.
- The Colour of Magic, aired by Sky One, Easter 2008 as TV film.
- Going Postal, aired by Sky One, Easter 2010 as TV film.

Comment: Truckers, Johnny and the Dead and Johnny and the Bomb are not set in Discworld although Terry Prachett was their Author.

Comment: @Sarriesfan Fair point and correct. Notwithstanding those then, I think the list is exhaustive. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Going to [IMDB](http://imdb.com) and entering Terry Pratchett's name will get you a list of everything - existing and proposed - that he has written. You've listed most of them.

British DVDs will not play on most North American players. It's not about the region locking, it's about the TV format (PAL vs NTSC). You can buy players that will play if you look.

Fortunately most of PTerry's works are available in North American format in the usual online stores.

Comment: US DVDs play fine in UK and Australian players - can't see why the reverse would be any different.